# Select option filter plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to add a select option filter, which means that the table itself will hide the td if that does not match the value of the selected option. It is not an issue for me to write a code for search input filter, but I am stuck with the the select option filter. Anyone who know how I get that fixed. Only in plain JavaScript, no other frameworks allowed.

```js
function filterDepartment() {
  var selectJob = document.getElementById("selectJob"),
    table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    department = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    console.log(department);

    if (department) {

      if (department.innerHTML.indexOf() > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("change", filterDepartment);
```

```html
<div class="article-block">
  <div class="inner-block">
    <div class="tabel-block">

      <div class="three-column column-padding search-bar">
        <select name="department" id="selectJob" />
        <option value="All Department" selected="selected">All Departments</option>
        <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
        <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
          <th class="table-header">Department</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Europe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Europe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Europe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Asia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Asia</td>
        </tr>c
        <tr>
          <td>Asia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Asia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Asia</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You do not execute your script.

Comment: I have added an addEventListener to it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You want to filter on cell 1 but cells start at 0
2. You needed to call the function onchange of the select `document.getElementById("selectJob").addEventListener("change", filterDepartment);` will work
3. You needed to test there was something selected to show all departments
4. I removed a stray `c` too from your html

```js
function filterDepartment() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
    selected = this.value;
  for (var i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    var department = tr[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
    if (department) {
      tr[i].style.display=selected=="" || department.indexOf(selected) > -1 ?"":"none";
    }
  }
}
window.onload=function() { // or addEventListener/attachEvent
  document.getElementById("selectJob").addEventListener("change", filterDepartment);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="article-block">
  <div class="inner-block">
    <div class="tabel-block">

      <div class="three-column column-padding search-bar">
        <select name="department" id="selectJob" />
        <option value="" selected="selected">All Departments</option>
        <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
        <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
          <th class="table-header">Department</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Europe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Europe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Europe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Asia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Asia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Asia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Asia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Asia</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have removed the unnecessary cells, there are now one cell left. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterDepartment() {
    var selectJob = document.getElementById("selectJob"), 
        table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for(var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

        department = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; // use [0] as the first `td`
        console.log(department);

        if(department && department.innerHTML.indexOf(selectJob.value) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";   
        }

    }
}

// listen to select changes
  document.querySelector('#selectJob').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    filterDepartment();
  });
```